# How can I sum the distinct selection in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    SUM(`PR Requests`),
    CAR,
    Request_State
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Po_Line_Amount AS `PR Requests`,
            Project_Code AS CAR,
            Request_State
        FROM
            Table1
        WHERE NOT (
            Request_State LIKE '%canceled%'
            OR Request_State LIKE '%pulled_back%'
        )
    ) t
```

That query works and returns the distinct amounts summed up properly.  I tried to then get those out in a larger query:

```
SELECT ID, Title, `Start Date`, `7ca. CAR` AS CAR, b.PR, c.Capex, c.PO_Committed AS `PO Committed`, c.PO_Invoiced AS `PO Invoiced`
FROM Table3 a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    SUM(`PR Requests`) AS PR,
    CAR,
    Request_State
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Po_Line_Amount AS `PR Requests`,
            Project_Code AS CAR,
            Request_State
        FROM
            Table1
        WHERE NOT (
            Request_State LIKE '%canceled%'
            OR Request_State LIKE '%pulled_back%'
        )
    ) t
) b ON b.CAR = a.`7ca. CAR`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Car_Number, SUM(Capex) AS Capex, SUM(PO_Committed) AS PO_Committed, SUM(PO_Invoiced) AS PO_Invoiced
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Car_Number
) c ON c.Car_Number = a.`7ca. CAR`
WHERE `Snapshot` = (SELECT MAX(`Snapshot`) FROM RandD_Playbook)
AND NOT ISNULL(PO_Committed)
GROUP BY
    ID, Title
```

This runs, but it gives me NULL for PR where I was expecting to get the SUM of the PR Requests.  Am I aliasing wrong?

Comment: Execute each sub queries one at a time and see if you get the expected result. Also, give us sample data to work on. Thanks.

Comment: all of these queries were built on their own initially and worked.  If I take out the SELECT DISTINCT portion and just use the query without that piece it works fine and returns values.  The problem is that there is a duplication(triplication actually) in the Table1 data and I don't own the data incoming to that table.

Comment: As for sample data, I will have to see what I can do; it is not a simple set to make as it needs at least 3 tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out; on a whim I tried adding a group by after the t for the SELECT DISTINCT code.

```
SELECT ID, Title, `Start Date`, `7ca. CAR` AS CAR, b.PR, c.Capex, c.PO_Committed AS `PO Committed`, c.PO_Invoiced AS `PO Invoiced`
FROM Table3 a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    SUM(`PR Requests`) AS PR,
    CAR,
    Request_State
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Po_Line_Amount AS `PR Requests`,
            Project_Code AS CAR,
            Request_State
        FROM
            Table1
        WHERE NOT (
            Request_State LIKE '%canceled%'
            OR Request_State LIKE '%pulled_back%'
        )
    ) t
  GROUP BY CAR
) b ON b.CAR = a.`7ca. CAR`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Car_Number, SUM(Capex) AS Capex, SUM(PO_Committed) AS PO_Committed, SUM(PO_Invoiced) AS PO_Invoiced
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Car_Number
) c ON c.Car_Number = a.`7ca. CAR`
WHERE `Snapshot` = (SELECT MAX(`Snapshot`) FROM RandD_Playbook)
AND NOT ISNULL(PO_Committed)
GROUP BY
    ID, Title
```

that cleared up the NULL.  Not sure why that is required there, but it works in all cases so that is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If `PR` is  NULL, and since you're doing a LEFT JOIN, this can only mean that there are no results from on the condition of `b.CAR = a.7ca. CAR`

Comment: except that it's not NULL when I pull it on it's own with a known good match on the CAR.

Comment: Pulling the records on it's own is different than joining it w/ multiple tables, especially when you're dealing with `LEFT JOINS` and `GROUP BY`s. I would guess that your `b` or `c` table do not satisfy one of the conditions which is yielding a `NULL`. Your `GROUP BY` could be returning the NULL record vs the found `PR` record.

For example, if you erased the two `LEFT JOIN`s and just made them a `JOIN`, you wouldn't get the entire dataset you were expecting, but i bet every record would have a `PR` value.

Comment: I was able to get it fixed; you can see my answer above.